# Kottlin app closes right after launching - App Error

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I'm developing my first app in kotlin. I stumbled uppon this error where my app closes right after it launches. I have implemented a menu and was now in the process of creating a grid view with some images for the main page. I do not know what is causing this error, but I do know it has something to do with the grid view code since I've implemented the menu first and the app worked just fine. Can it be because I am trying to do the grid view in a fragment and not directly in the MainActivity view?

MainActivity.kt

---

```
val TAG = "MainActivity"

    lateinit var gridView: GridView
    private var gridImageNames = arrayOf(
        "Golden Bridge", "Tampa Bay Buccaneers", "Chevrolet Camaro",
        "Vegetable Casserole", "Sweet and Sour Chicken", "Design Vector",
        "Pork Loin", "Sidney's Opera House", "Pasta Dish",
        "Dope Setup", "Singapore", "Tacos Dish",
        "Toquio", "Warm Salad Dish")
    private var gridImages = intArrayOf(
        R.drawable.bridge, R.drawable.buccaneers, R.drawable.camaro,
        R.drawable.casserole, R.drawable.chicken, R.drawable.design,
        R.drawable.lombo, R.drawable.operahouse, R.drawable.pasta,
        R.drawable.setup, R.drawable.singapore, R.drawable.tacos,
        R.drawable.toquio, R.drawable.warmsalad)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val bottom_navigation: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation)
        gridView = findViewById(R.id.home_grid)
        val mainAdapter = MainAdapter(this@MainActivity, gridImageNames, gridImages)
        gridView.adapter = mainAdapter

        val homeFragment = HomeFragment()
        val listsFragment = ListsFragment()
        val searchFragment = SearchFragment()

        bottom_navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.nav_home -> {
                    setCurrentFragment(homeFragment)
                    Log.i(TAG, "Home Selected")
                }
                R.id.nav_lists -> {
                    setCurrentFragment(listsFragment)
                    Log.i(TAG, "My Lists Selected")
                }
                R.id.nav_search -> {
                    setCurrentFragment(searchFragment)
                    Log.i(TAG, "Search Selected")
                }
            }
            true
        }

        gridView.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
            Toast.makeText(
                applicationContext, "You Clicked " + gridImageNames[+position],
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
    }

    private fun setCurrentFragment(fragment : Fragment) =
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            replace(R.id.fl_wrapper, fragment)
            commit()
        }
```

MyAdapter.kt

---

```
internal class MainAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private val imageNames: Array<String>,
    private val images: IntArray
) : BaseAdapter(){
    private var layoutInflater: LayoutInflater? = null
    private lateinit var imageView: ImageView

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return imageNames.size
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any? {
        return null
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return 0
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View? {
        var convertView = convertView
        if (layoutInflater == null) {
            layoutInflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        }
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = layoutInflater!!.inflate(R.layout.home_grid_row, null)
        }

        imageView = convertView!!.findViewById(R.id.grid_image)
        imageView.setImageResource(images[position])
        return convertView
    }
}
```

home_grid_row.xml

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
    
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/grid_image"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_home.xml

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/home_grid"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat Error Message:

---

```
2021-01-19 18:08:10.127 6067-6067/cm.a12872_a18797.favlist E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: cm.a12872_a18797.favlist, PID: 6067
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cm.a12872_a18797.favlist/cm.a12872_a18797.favlist.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: findViewById(R.id.home_grid) must not be null
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3961)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2386)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: findViewById(R.id.home_grid) must not be null
        at cm.a12872_a18797.favlist.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:38)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8086)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8074)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3755)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3961) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2386) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
```

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: there is no error message. The app just closes right after it is launched

Comment: Could you post corresponding error from logcat, please?

Comment: @S-Sh I added the logcat error message in the end of the question

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking for a view with the id `R.id.home_grid` but it does not exist. Check your `activity_main` layout file and verify `R.id.home_grid` is there.

Comment: my grid view is being created in a fragment called fragment_home.xml. I will add the code to the question

Comment: @MachineTheGod Well you are declaring the view in the `MainActivity` with ` gridView = findViewById(R.id.home_grid)`

Comment: yes, because I am using a menu that shows fragments in the MainActivity instead of using other activities. Also I tried writing the code that belongs to the gridview in the HomeFragment kotlin file but I immediately understood it didn't work because there were error that the MainActivity didn't show

Comment: @MachineTheGod Simply remove  `gridView = findViewById(R.id.home_grid)` from your main activity.

Comment: I removed it and although it is not showing an error on AS, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @MachineTheGod Well that fixed your error. Post another question of you need. Good luck!

Comment: I probably didn't exposed the problem correctly, but I was not having an error on AS. The problem is when I launch the app that immediately shuts down

Answer (score 0):

There is no view with id `R.id.home_grid` when you try to get it with `findViewById` in the Activity. According the XML, the GridView presents in the fragment, so, I suggest move all setup for GridView into the fragment:

```kotlin
    lateinit var gridView: GridView
    private var gridImageNames = arrayOf(
        "Golden Bridge", "Tampa Bay Buccaneers", "Chevrolet Camaro",
        "Vegetable Casserole", "Sweet and Sour Chicken", "Design Vector",
        "Pork Loin", "Sidney's Opera House", "Pasta Dish",
        "Dope Setup", "Singapore", "Tacos Dish",
        "Toquio", "Warm Salad Dish")
    private var gridImages = intArrayOf(
        R.drawable.bridge, R.drawable.buccaneers, R.drawable.camaro,
        R.drawable.casserole, R.drawable.chicken, R.drawable.design,
        R.drawable.lombo, R.drawable.operahouse, R.drawable.pasta,
        R.drawable.setup, R.drawable.singapore, R.drawable.tacos,
        R.drawable.toquio, R.drawable.warmsalad)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        gridView = view.findViewById(R.id.home_grid)
        val mainAdapter = MainAdapter(this@MainActivity, gridImageNames, gridImages)
        gridView.adapter = mainAdapter

        gridView.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
            Toast.makeText(
                applicationContext, "You Clicked " + gridImageNames[+position],
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
    }
```

And set fragments in Activity:

```kotlin
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val homeFragment = HomeFragment()
        val listsFragment = ListsFragment()
        val searchFragment = SearchFragment()
        setCurrentFragment(homeFragment)

        // bottom navigaton setup, etc
    }
```

Comment: @MachineTheGod I have updated the answer, please try and let me know result